# Package does not exist when attempting to run java file on powershell

Tags: java, powershell

I have an eclipse project named PackageTest with two packages with one file inside each.: src/apple/Apple.java and src/test/Main.java.

Here is the code of both:

```
package test;
import apple.Apple;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Apple apple = new Apple(5);
    }
}
```

```
package apple;

public class Apple {
    
    private int value;
    
    public Apple(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I can run Main.java just fine from inside eclipse, but when I try to use:

```
java (rest of directory)\PackageTest\src\test\Main.java
```

On the command line, I receive this error:

```
import apple.Apple;
            ^
Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
         Apple apple = new Apple(5);
         ^
  symbol:   class Apple
  location: class Main
Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
         Apple apple = new Apple(5);
                           ^
  symbol:   class Apple
  location: class Main
3 errors
error: compilation failed
```

And yes, I have tried

```
java (rest of directory)\PackageTest\src\test\Main.java --cp (rest of directory)\PackageTest
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java source code packages as one big hierarchical namespace.
Try change to folder structure for Apple Class. The project need a main/java folder for java class.

src/**main/java**/apple/Apple.java

Example:

```
src/test/java/com/acme/foo/BarTest.java
src/main/java/com/acme/foo/Bar.java
```

Regards.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).